# Laravel Eloquent/DB: Multiple sum fields in grouped select

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there any possibility to do the following simple sql-select in Laravel?

SELECT a,b,c,d, SUM(e) as e, SUM(f) as f, SUM(g) as g FROM my_table GROUP BY a,b,c,d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `DB` class for that:

```
DB::table('my_table')
    ->select('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', DB::raw('SUM(e) as e'), DB::raw('SUM(f) as f'), DB::raw('SUM(g) as g'))
    ->groupBy('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
    ->get()
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries)

Comment: Sorry, took a while to test this out and check it.
This works fine, the sums are correct.

I tried several methods of that before, but maybe this solution seemed to be to easy to be thought of... ,-)

Thanks for your help taering down my thinking barrier!